# How to distinguish the views after View.generateViewId ()?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

please tell me. How can I distinguish between the buttons after generateVievId()? Do I need to create some extra data structure, and to save all generated ids, and then from there to compare?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always distinguish between views by setting an unique tag to each of them, calling View.setTag() and then getting the tag by calling View.getTag()

Not clear though why you can not just get all the buttons using Activity.findViewById() save them as Activity fields and operate on those fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Because I create views dynamically. With ids was convenient before.